# shell command meaning(backslash and grep)

Tags: bash, grep

I mistyped |(bar) as \ (backslash)

```
locate abcdef \ grep 2
```

like this. Then bash start to find all files that include '2' in their name.
Why this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command:

```
locate abcdef \ grep 2
```

made rest of text after `locate` i.e. `\ grep 2` as arguments for `locate` command hence it started processing `locate` command (grep didn't execute at all).

Comment: +1 It's worth noting what the backslash does as well as doesn't do. The second argument is ' grep' (with leading space), with '2' as the third argument.

Comment: Yes agreed with @chepner.

Answer (score 3):

The backslash just escaped the space after it from being interpreted by the shell as a delimiter of arguments.  So what you now called was the `locate` command with three arguments, the first being `abcdef`, the second being  `grep` (with a leading space), and the third being `2`.

`locate` in such a case lists all the files which have *at least one* of the search terms in them.

Answer (score 0):

your command will locate the all files in the system which has 2 in its file name.  Because \ is a globbing character, which disables the implicit replacement of `NAME by *NAME*`.

```
locate filename \ grep 2
```

this will neglect the filename and start searching for for file which has 2 in its filename

Comment: '\' is not a globbing character; it merely escapes the following space so that 'filename', ' grep' (with leading space), and '2' are the three arguments to `locate`.